# Deserialize Protobuf datetime?

Tags: python, c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to deserialize the `datetime?` data serialized using Protobuf from Redis records. (They are not epoch numbers).

I found the following integers (left) in the Redis records (serialized `datetime?` as protobuf).

```
 1354218408 => "2023-02-02T04:51:19.5480532Z"
 2719022476 => "2023-02-01T13:43:21.7035974Z"
 3430755584 => "2023-02-01T14:01:51.0320768Z"
 2719022538 => "2023-02-01T13:43:21.7036005Z"
  674672264 => "2023-02-02T04:14:58.087098Z"
 2184901194 => "2023-02-02T21:32:05.7918176Z"
```

The following is the raw protobuf for "2023-02-02T04:15:41.406221Z" (`datetime?`).

```
 {
     "2": [
         {
             "1": 1541054724
         }
     ]
 },
```

Given a serialized integer, how to convert it to datetime?

I tried the following python code and it doesn't get the right number.

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = 1354218408  # Example integer representing a timestamp
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
print(dt)
```

It prints `2012-11-29 14:46:48` instead of "2023-02-02T04:51:19.5480532Z"

Comment: A typical datetime value should be 64 bits long, did you serialize the datetime to a wrong size?

Comment: I found these values in Redis db, and got the datetimes via the Web API. As I know the Web app uses Protobuf to serialize the `datetime?` for Redis.

Comment: I'm confused, do you have a Web API that can convert these numbers on the left to the datetimes on the right? Are the Web API and the Web App the same thing?

Comment: It's someone else's web application. Yes, there are the same thing. sorry

Comment: Just like I commented before, the integers are generated from the internal 64-bit integer in datetime. Confirmed by C# https://dotnetfiddle.net/lFf05c The error may be caused by different implementations of datetime, but no doubt these results were truncated to 32-bit. You may connect the author.

Comment: Thanks, you nailed how the integers are generated. However, what I need to do is restoring the datetime from the integers. It seems some part of number is gone after cast it to uint. I tried `new DateTime((x + 4016766976L) /2)` but it doesn't get the right date time.

Comment: It can't be restored now because of the data loss. You need to find out the reason.

Comment: Found out it needs to be `new DateTime ( (x + 1276218200219975680L + 4016766976)/2)`. No idea about those magic numbers.

Comment: It seems the integers in my question are just some information of the time parts....

Comment: It just called redisCacheClient.Db0.HashGetAllAsync(key) and the correct date times are returned. Maybe Redis save the date part some where....

Comment: No these integers in the redis are just worthless, I don't know how they were generated and how they were stored in the redis, but redis is not the problem, the problem is from the manufacturer or the stored procedure.

Comment: Just to add: protobuf does not handle datetimes as primitives; the most common representation of datetimes in protobuf is probably [timestamp](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto) (although others exist), and timestamp is *two* numbers, not one; so they're doing something bespoke, and as discussed already above: possibly incorrectly

Comment: you tagged this protobuf-net; if you're actually using protobuf-net here, I might be able to help more, but seeing the classes involved would help (I'm the author of both protobuf-net and StackExchange.Redis, so... yeah)

Comment: Nice. Yes, the code actually uses protobuf-net. I found that `DateTimeOffset` is serialized to a string representation of date time. I will get the class from my work computer tomorrow. It's like `class { ..., [...] DateTime? ReportDate; ... }`